# Create custom paging control

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm not certain of what HTML or ASP.NET  control I could use to create a paging control.

I have a gridview which has a huge number of columns, so normal paging examples won't work.  So I need a control to simply .take() and .skip() on the datasource to render only the columns to be displayed.

The problem is I don't know the best way to go about doing this.  I think a repeater may work, but I don't know if that would be the best solution.  Any insight here would be great.  thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: "columns" or "rows"?

Comment: Are you talking about Classic ASP or ASP.net?  Your talk of controls and repeaters suggests the latter.